# Filling boolean 2D array from text file

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, text-files

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to input data from a text file into a two dimensional array. The data I'm trying to import is primarily a series of 1 and 0s, but with a couple of characters (S and G) as well. The point of this exercise is to create a maze game with the 0s and 1s indicating if a space is blocked or not with the S indicating the start and G the goal. I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to be properly importing my text file to create the initial maze layout. The main errors I'm receiving are either array out of bounds or it's telling me the maze is formatted incorrectly.

This is the code for the entirety of the class

```
package solution;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A maze game.
 * 
 * @author Nicholas Thomas
 * @version 8/30/2018
 *
 */
public class MazeGame
{
    /**
     * The size of each side of the game map.
     */
    private final static int HEIGHT = 19;
    private final static int WIDTH = 39;

    /**
     * The game map, as a 2D array of ints.
     */
    private boolean[][] blocked = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    /**
     * The current location of the player vertically.
     */
    // TODO: add field here.
    int userCol;
    /**
     * The current location of the player horizontally.
     */
    // TODO: add field here.
    int userRow;
    /**
     * The scanner from which each move is read.
     */
    // TODO: add field here.
    Scanner moveScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    /**
     * The row and column of the goal.
     */
    // TODO: add fields here.

    /**
     * The row and column of the start.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    // TODO: add fields here.

    /**
     * Accessor method for the Blocked array.
     * 
     * @param Blocked
     * 
     * @return Blocked
     * 
     */
    public boolean[][] getBlocked()
    {
        return blocked;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method to return the user col.
     * 
     * @return userCol
     */
    public int getUserCol()
    {
        return userCol;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor to get userRow.
     * 
     * @return userRow
     */
    public int getUserRow()
    {
        return userRow;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method to get scanner contents.
     * 
     */
    public Scanner getMoveScanner()
    {
        return moveScanner;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator method for the blocked array.
     * 
     */
    public void setBlocked(boolean[][] blocked)
    {
        this.blocked = blocked;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator method for the userCol.
     */
    public void setUserCol(int col)
    {
        this.userCol = col;
    }

    public void setUserRow(int row)
    {
        this.userRow = row;

    }

    public void setMoveScanner(Scanner moveScanner)
    {
        this.moveScanner = moveScanner;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor initializes the maze with the data in 'mazeFile'.
     * 
     * @param mazeFile
     *            the input file for the maze
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public MazeGame(String mazeFile)
    {
        loadMaze(mazeFile);
        moveScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    }

    /**
     * Constructor initializes the maze with the 'mazeFile' and the move scanner
     * with 'moveScanner'.
     * 
     * @param mazeFile
     *            the input file for the maze
     * @param moveScanner
     *            the scanner object from which to read user moves
     */
    public MazeGame(String mazeFile, Scanner moveScanner)
    {
        loadMaze(mazeFile);
        this.moveScanner = moveScanner;
    }

    /**
     * getMaze returns a copy of the current maze for testing purposes.
     * 
     * @return the grid
     */
    public boolean[][] getMaze()
    {
        if (blocked == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        boolean[][] copy = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
            {
                copy[i][j] = blocked[i][j];
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }

    /**
     * setMaze sets the current map for testing purposes.
     * 
     * @param maze
     *            another maze.
     */
    public void setMaze(boolean[][] maze)
    {
        this.blocked = maze;
    }

    /**
     * Function loads the data from the maze file and creates the 'blocked' 2D
     * array.
     * 
     * @param mazeFile
     *            the input maze file.
     */
    // TODO: private void loadMaze(String mazeFile)

    /**
     * Actually plays the game.
     */
    public void playGame()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if the player has won the game.
     * 
     * @return true if the player has won.
     */
    // TODO: public boolean playerAtGoal()

    /**
     * Makes a move based on the String.
     * 
     * @param move
     *            the direction to make a move in.
     * @return whether the move was valid.
     */
    public boolean makeMove(String move)
    {
        // TODO
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the map of the maze.
     */
    public void printMaze()
    {
        // TODO
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new game, using a command line argument file name, if one is
     * provided.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String mapFile = "data/easy.txt";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        MazeGame game = new MazeGame(mapFile, scan);
        game.playGame();
    }

    /**
     * Method to crate the maze from file.
     * 
     * @param mazeFile
     *
     */
    public void loadMaze(String mazeFile)
    {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try
        {
            String var;
            scanner = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));
            boolean[][] blocked = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
            for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
                {
                    if (scanner.hasNext())
                    {
                        var =scanner.next();

                        if (var == "1")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = true;
                        }
                        if (var == "0")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = false;
                        }
                        if (var == "S")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = false;
                        }
                        if (var == "G")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = false;
                        }
                        System.out.print(blocked[i][j] + ",");
                    }
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is what the text file I'm trying to import looks like.

```
S 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 G 
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

This is the first thing I attempted trying to fill the array, but no luck with this.

```
 /**
     * Method to crate the maze from file.
     * 
     * @param mazeFile
     */
    public void loadMaze(String mazeFile)
    {
        String fileName = ("C:/users/thomasns/easy.txt");
        // File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanMan = new Scanner(fileName);
        boolean blocked[][] = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
        while (scanMan.hasNext())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < blocked.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < blocked[i].length; j++)
                {
                    blocked[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = scanMan.nextBoolean();
                }
                scanMan.close();
            }

        }
    }
```

This is another implementation I've been attempting, as of now I can only get this to return false for everything.

```
  /**
     * Method to crate the maze from file.
     * 
     * @param mazeFile
     *
     */
    public void loadMaze(String mazeFile)
    {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try
        {
            String var;
            scanner = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));
            boolean[][] blocked = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
            for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
                {
                    if (scanner.hasNext())
                    {
                        var =scanner.next();

                        if (var == "1")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = true;
                        }
                        if (var == "0")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = false;
                        }
                        if (var == "S")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = false;
                        }
                        if (var == "G")
                        {
                            blocked[i][j] = false;
                        }
                        System.out.print(blocked[i][j] + ",");
                    }
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

If anyone has any advice for me I'd greatly appreciate it, thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the errors you getting? and what are the output of your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

First method of yours could work, but you got your indexes wrong as they are constant

Insteed of

```
 blocked[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = scanMan.nextBoolean();
```

you should rather

```
 blocked[j][i] = scanMan.nextBoolean(); // or other way around.
```

Second might work but this is not how you compare strings, so insteed of

```
 if (var == "1")
```

should be

```
if (var.equals("1"))
```

By me, either read char by char and put it into array or read whole line, split, create array row, repeat.

First method could be something like this:

```
  boolean blocked[][] = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    int c=0;
    while (scanMan.hasNext()) {
       blocked[c/width][c%width]=scanMan.nextBoolean();
       c++;
    }
```

you would have to handle other chars then 1 and 0 i guess, but you should get rough idea.

Working example:

```
 public static void main(String... args) {
        String input =
                "S 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n" +
                "0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 \n" +
                "0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 \n" +
                "1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 \n" +
                "0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 \n" +
                "0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 \n" +
                "0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 \n" +
                "1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 \n" +
                "0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n" +
                "0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 \n" +
                "0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 G \n" +
                "0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 \n" +
                "0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 \n" +
                "0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 \n" +
                "0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 \n" +
                "0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 \n" +
                "0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 \n" +
                "1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 \n" +
                "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ";

        final int width = 39;
        final int heigh = 19;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        boolean[][] blocked = new boolean[heigh][width];

        int c = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String character = scan.next();
            switch (character) {
                case "S"://do something; break;
                    System.out.println("Detected S");
                    break;
                case "G"://so something;
                    System.out.println("Detected G");
                    break;
                default:
                    blocked[c / width][c % width] = Boolean.valueOf(character);
            }
            c++;
        }

}
```